# ¿Cómo hacer un panel colapsable en bootstrap3 y PHP?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenía un panel colapsable en Bootstrap que funcionaba, pero en cuanto cambié la página a PHP no funciona, el panel me aparece siempre abierto y quiero que al ingresar a la página aparezca cerrado y pueda abrirse y cerrarse, ya que las opciones que he encontrado, al correrlo en la página, solo abren pero no vuelven a cerrar o me aparecen abiertas, también intenté con `.toggle()`pero no quiero que sea de dos botones.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1"><h3 class="center-block; text-center"><strong class="text-center center-block">1er Ciclo de Conferencias <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right"></span></strong></h3></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body"><div class="row">

      <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <h4 align="center">Título</h4>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> Contenido </aside> <br>
      </section>
```

Lo hice con `<aside>` y `<section>` porque requiero que tenga columnas dentro de cada acordeón.

Este es otro recurso que encontré, pero no funciona completamente, ya que no colapsa, solo abre el acordeón.

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footwear" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="footwear">
Heading
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="footwear">
<p>Collapsible content...</p>
</div>
```

Actualización: Quité la clase `in` como sugerencia de @alanfcm pero no vuelve a colapsar. Aunque sí aparece cerrada por default, @Elon.SSH me pidió que colocara el PHP completo, así que aquí está:

```
<?php $title = "Eventos - Laboratorios Chontalpa";
include_once 'temps/header.html';
?>


    <!--seccionesservicios-->
<div>
<!--Título-->
    <div id="titulo" class="row">
        <div id="tituloppal" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 center-block text-center"> <h1><strong>Eventos</strong></h1>

        </div>
    </div>


<!--Prueba acordeón-->


  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1"><h3 class="center-block; text-center"><strong class="text-center center-block">1er Ciclo de Conferencias <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right"></span></strong></h3></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><div class="row">


      <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 5%">
         <h4 align="center"><strong>Obesidad y su impacto en la salud</strong></h4>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><a href="abril.html">
          <img src="images/eventos/abril.jpg" width="125px" class="img-responsive" alt="Obesidad y su impacto en la salud"></a></aside>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 5px">
          <strong>CV Ponente</strong>
          <br><a href="images/eventos/abril/curriculum_alejandro.pdf" alt="Dr. José Alejandro Chávez Fernández">Dr. José Alejandro Chávez Fernández</a><br>
          <br><strong>Conferencia</strong><br>
          <br><button type="submit" width="60px" class="btn-default"><img src="images/visualizacion-01.svg" alt="visualizar"  width="16px"><a href="images/eventos/abril/video.mp4">Visualizar</a></button>


          </aside><br>
      </section>

     <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 5%">
         <h4 align="center"><strong>Utilidad de las pruebas cardiopulmonares</strong></h4>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><a href="mayo.html">
          <img src="images/eventos/mayo.jpg" width="125px" class="img-responsive" alt="Utilidad de las pruebas cardiopulmonares"></a></aside>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 5px">
          <strong>CV Ponente</strong>
          <br><a href="images/eventos/mayo/curriculum_daniel_ivan.pdf" download="Currículum_DR_Daniel-Ivan-Perez-Vasquez" alt="Dr. Daniel Iván Pérez Vásquez">Dr. Daniel Iván Pérez Vásquez</a><br>
          <br><strong>Conferencia</strong><br>
          <a href="images/eventos/mayo/Utlidad-de-la-PEAGETabasco_web.pdf">Diapositivas</a><br>
          <br><button type="submit" width="60px" class="btn-default"><img src="images/visualizacion-01.svg" alt="visualizar"  width="16px"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LaboratoriosChontalpa/videos/1753786761349906/">Visualizar</a></button>

          </aside><br>
      </section>

       <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 5%">
         <h4 align="center"><strong>Biología Molecular y su uso clínico</strong></h4>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><a href="#">
          <img src="images/eventos/junio.jpg" width="125px" class="img-responsive" alt="Utilidad de las pruebas de biología molecular (PCR)"></a></aside>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 5px">
          <strong>CV Ponentes</strong>
          <br><a href="images/eventos/junio/curriculum_biologia_molecular.pdf" alt="Dr. Aurelio Cruz Valdez">Dr. Aurelio Cruz Valdez</a>
          <br><a href="images/eventos/junio/curriculum_biologia_molecular.pdf" alt="Dr. Jacobo Zúñiga Castillo">Dr. Jacobo Zúñiga Castillo</a><br>
          <br><strong>Conferencia</strong><br>
          <br><button type="submit" width="60px" class="btn-default"><img src="images/visualizacion-01.svg" alt="visualizar"  width="16px"><a href="#">Visualizar</a></button>


          </aside><br>
      </section>

               <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 5%">
         <h4 align="center"><strong>Infecciones Respiratorias de Vías Altas:<br /><i>Nuevo enfoque diagnóstico</i></strong></h4>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><a href="#">
          <img src="images/eventos/julio.jpg" width="125px" class="img-responsive" alt="Utilidad de las pruebas de biología molecular (PCR)"></a></aside>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 5px">
          <strong>CV Ponentes</strong>
          <br><a href="images/eventos/julio/Curriculum.pdf" alt="Dr. Johnny Oswaldo Santamaría Paredes">Dr. Johnny Oswaldo Santamaría Paredes</a>
          <br><a href="images/eventos/julio/Curriculum.pdf" alt="Dr. Jorge Armando Cime Castillo">Dr. Jorge Armando Cime Castillo</a><br>
          <br><strong>Conferencia</strong><br>
          <br><button type="submit" width="60px" class="btn-default"><img src="images/visualizacion-01.svg" alt="visualizar"  width="16px"><a href="#">Visualizar</a></button>


          </aside><br>
      </section>


      </div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<?php
include_once('temps/footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: si tienes tu codigo html en un docuemento php, puedes colocar todo el codigo entero?, es decir desde <?php hasta ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que quitar la clase `in` de tu panel.  Quedaria asi:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1"><h3 class="center-block; text-center"><strong class="text-center center-block">1er Ciclo de Conferencias <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right"></span></strong></h3></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><div class="row">

      <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <h4 align="center">Título</h4>
      <aside class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> Contenido </aside> <br>
      </section>
```

Comment: Resolvió el problema de aparecer "open" por default, pero una vez que abre, no vuelve a cerrar.

Comment: Aqui si funciona bien como puedes ver.